# C++ code throwing Seg. Fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a C++ code as follow:

tryIt.h file

```
class tryIt : public someOtherClass
{
public:
       bool insertI ();
private:
       CommandI* m_pInsertI;
       bool createInsertI();
}
```

tryIt.cpp file

```
tryIt ::tryIt () : m_pInsertI(NULL)
{
    createInsertI();
}

tryIt ::~tryIt ()
{
   if(m_pInsertI!=NULL)
   {
      delete m_pInsertI;
      m_pInsertI=NULL
   }
}
bool createInsertI()
{
    m_pInsertI = returnFromSomeOtherFunction();
    return true;
}

bool insertI()
{
    // Over here if I use m_pInsertI anyhow my code fails with seg fault
    // even checking if(m_pInsertI==NULL) make the code throw seg fault
}
```

So the issue is touching m_pInsertI anywhere make my code throw Seg. fault (Signal 11). Even debugged the code with GDB but didn't got any useful info.

Compiler is GCC

Please help.

Comment: Can you show `returnFromSomeOtherFunction()` and `insertI()`?

Comment: @Morb - It's a complicated return from many function. Any specific question here?

Comment: The creation of `m_pInsertI` could have a problem.
Have you tried to print the address of this variable right after creation?

Comment: I don't suppose your instances of `tryIt` are ever passed around by *value* ? Copied? Assigned to another `tryIt` instance? Does your *real* code comply with the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29) ?

Comment: @Morb - Yes I tried printing the address and I am getting a valid address.

Comment: Assuming you declared-private (or C++11's `delete`) the copy-ctor and copy-assignment operators and your code *still builds*, thus reducing any chances of RO3 violations, then my bets are on the instance of `tryIt` itself, or the pointer returned to you. At-best one of them is bad. Is the secret `m_pInsertI` usable immediately after the retrieval in `createInsertI`, and is `this` the *same* address both in `createInsertI` and the crashing destructor?

Comment: And since you debugged this in gdb, post the crash log with backtrace (bt) in your question. Maybe it will be more useful to us than it was to you.

Comment: "tryIt ::tryIt () : m_pInsertI(NULL)" - Did you mean "tryIt ::tryIt () : someOtherClass(NULL)"? As it is, it's calling a function on a member of a class that's not yet been initialized.

Comment: @Mike - No, I meant "tryIt ::tryIt () : m_pInsertI(NULL)" only

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the instance of this class does not exist or damaged.
That is why you can't access any of its members and even if(m_pInsertI==NULL) check raises the exception.

Answer (score 0):

in tryIt.cpp shouldn't

```
bool createInsertI()
```

be

```
bool tryIt::createInsertI()
```

same with insertI()

Answer (score 0):

I see the following **two possibilities**:

- `returnFromSomeOtherFunction()` already returns a corrupted pointer
- You are copying your instance using the compiler generated methods (see example below)

*Example* (Rule of three violation)

```
tryIt instance1; // allocates instance2.m_pInsertI

{
    tryIt instance2;
    instance1 = instance 2; // performs a shallow copy

} // here, instance2.m_pInsertI is deleted

instance1.insertI(); // access violation
```

**Recommendation:**

Whether or not this is cause your problem: Do not implement manual memory management. Simply use a `std::unique_ptr<CommandI>` for `m_pInsertI` instead, so you do not need to implement the destructor or copy constructors/operators.